# Hive installation issue on Apache Ambari HDP 2.5

Tags: hadoop, hive, ambari, analytics-for-apache-hdp, bigdata

I am getting following error when I am intalling Hive on Apache Ambari.

```
resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install hive2_2_5_3_0_37' returned 1. Error: Package: hive2_2_5_3_0_37-2.1.0.2.5.3.0-37.el6.noarch (HDP-2.5)
```

Do you know why this error occured ? Let me know your concerns.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to run `yum` command on affected node manually without suspended log output, like

```
/usr/bin/yum install hive2_2_5_3_0_37
```

And see full error message. Maybe package installation took too long time to complete and timed out, or maybe it's already installed.

Also, Ambari usually shows entire error output. Did you check stderr log, not only stdout log in "requests" dialog?